# Is it possible to use ngChange on <p> property to refresh value

Tags: angularjs

I am using `'ngMaterial'` module for dialogs. When user clicks edit prompt he can edit review. Everything works fine, except that you don't see that review is updated until you refresh page. Is it possible to make you see changes imediatelly?
This is my prompt function, which redirects user to `redirectEdit` function which puts changes to database.

These methods are in `main.controller.js`

```
$scope.showPrompt = function(ev,index) {
        var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
        .title('Edit your review')
        .placeholder('Review')
        .initialValue($scope.all[index].review)
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('Okay!')
        .cancel('Cancel');

        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
           $scope.redirectEdit(index,result);debugger;
        }, function() {
            $scope.status = 'You discarded changes.';
        });
    };




$scope.redirectEdit = function(index,result){debugger;
        $scope.all[index].id; console.log($scope.all[index].id);
        var JSONObject={
            "id":$scope.all[index].id,
            "name":$scope.all[index].name,
            "surname":$scope.all[index].surname,
            "email":$scope.all[index].email,
            "review":result
        }

        var Results = UniversalService.UpdateReview(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
};
```

this is my button in `main.view.html`
`<md-button ng-show="storageKey!==null" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="showPrompt($event,$index)" >Edit </md-button>`

```
<div class="row comment-table" ng-repeat="item in items ">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash[$index]}}" alt="Description" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>{{item.id}} Review posted by: {{item.name}}</p>           
                <p>{{item.review}}</p>
                <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max=5  on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></span>
                <span class="label" ng-class="{'label-warning': percent<30, 'label-info': percent>=30 && percent<70, 'label-success': percent>=70}" ng-show="overStar && !isReadonly">{{percent}}%</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Comment: I had seen plenty of your posts in stackoverflow since yesterday. Can't you try by yourself first instead of spoon feeding?

Comment: @Liam believe me, this is not "do this for me" question. I'm literally sitting trying to learn programming from 7am to midnight. I apologize if my question is too basic, I should have googled more maybe. My question was it is possible to use something like ngChange on <p> property. I should clarify my question a bit, sorry. I don't expect anyone to do it for me either.

Comment: @monikakalt Have you tried my assumption? Why should you use `ngChange`? You already have a 2-way data binding, just update the corresponding item in your `items` array.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the `review` property of the edited element like `$scope.all[index].review = result;` in your `scope.redirectEdit` method.